# Can't undo text edits in Document Viewer text annotations

Tags: evince

I'm unable to "undo" when I'm editing text in a Document Viewer text annotation.
(e.g. I accidentally deleted some text in the annotation and I want to undo that, like `Ctrl+Z` in gedit or Word).
I looked in Keyboard Shortcuts and in Help, but didn't find anything.
I swear I could do that on my old computer...

Document Viewer (Evince?) 3.36.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 with Gnome 3.36.8.

Comment: If you right click on the annotation, you will be presented with an option (amongst others) to `Remove Annotation`

Comment: I know how to remove an annotation. What I'm struggling with is how, when typing text inside the annotation (e.g. summarizing a paragraph with my own words), to undo a recent text manipulation (e.g. I accidentally deleted some text inside the annotation), similar to `Ctrl+Z` in Microsoft Word or gedit.

Comment: perhaps then, you should make that point clear by making an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same. Even if it may have worked in older versions, it does not appear to work in newer versions, also not for me in the latest Evince 40.1. A regression. Thus, be very careful when editing these annotations: no undo!